# c# do while loop exit even when the return is false

Tags: c#

I have this C# program that, and this loop doesn't want to exit, it just becomes a blank row until the user answers yes? Not sure why or how this is happening.
https://dotnetfiddle.net/A6vJtd

```
using System;
namespace Assignment2
{
    
    
    class FunFeatures
    {
        private string name = "";
        private string email = "";

                static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Title = "Strings, selection and interation in C#";
            FunFeatures funObj = new FunFeatures();
            funObj.Start();

            ContinueToNextPart(); //call the method below

        }

        private static void ContinueToNextPart()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nPress enter to continue to the next part");
            Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Clear();
        }
        
        public void Start()
        {
            Introduce();

            bool done = false;
            do
            {
                //Call method to read a number 1 to 7 and display
                //name of the day (1 = Monday, 7 = Sunday with a comment
                PredictTheDay();

                //Calculate the length of a given text
                CalculateStrengthLength();

                //Run again or exit
                done = RunAgain();
            } while (!done);
            Console.WriteLine("Welcome back, " + name);
        }



        public void CalculateStrengthLength()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nLength of text: Write a text with a number of characters and press Enter");
            Console.WriteLine("It will then calculate the number of chars included  in the text");
            Console.WriteLine("Give me a text of any length, or press Enter to exit!");
            string str = Console.ReadLine();
            int strLength = str.Length;
            Console.WriteLine("\n"+ str.ToUpper());
            Console.WriteLine("Number of chars = " + strLength);
        }

        private void Introduce()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nLet me know about yourself!");
            ReadName();
            Console.Write("Give me your email please: ");
            email = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("\nHere is your full name and your email.");

            //split first name and last name
            var names = name.Split(" ");
            string fName = names[0];
            string lName = names[1];

            Console.WriteLine(lName + ", " + fName + " " + email);
        }

        public void PredictTheDay()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(); // blank row
            Console.WriteLine("\nI am a fortune teller.");
            Console.Write("Select a number between 1 and 7: ");
            string str = Console.ReadLine();
            int day = int.Parse(str);


            switch (day)
            {
                case 1:
                    // Monday
                    Console.WriteLine("Monday: Keep calm my friend! You can fall apart!");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    //Tuesday
                    Console.WriteLine("Tuesday and Wednesday break your heart!");
                    break;
                case 3:
                    //Wednesday
                    Console.WriteLine("Tuesday and Wednesday break your heart!");
                    break;
                case 4:
                    //Thursday
                    Console.WriteLine("Thursday, OMG, still one day to Friday!");
                    break;
                case 5:
                    //Friday
                    Console.WriteLine("It's Friday! You are in love!");
                    break;
                case 6:
                    //Saturday
                    Console.WriteLine("Saturday, do nothing and do plenty of it!");
                    break;
                case 7:
                    //Sunday
                    Console.WriteLine("And Sunday always comes too soon!");
                    break;

                default: // if user gives a number out of range
                    Console.WriteLine("Not in a good mode? This is not a valid date!");
                    break;
            }
        }

        public void ReadName()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Your first name please: ");
            string firstname = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Your last name please: ");
            string lastname = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();
            name = firstname + " " + lastname;
            Console.WriteLine("Nice to meet you " + firstname + "!");
        }

        //Ask user to whether to continue, 
        //return true if the user answers Y, y or any word beginning
        //with these, or N, n or any word beginning with these. 
        //Otherwise, return false.
        private bool RunAgain()
        {
            bool done = false; //true = y, false = n

            Console.WriteLine(); //blankline
            Console.Write("Run again? (y/n) ");

            do
            {
                string str = Console.ReadLine();
                //change str to uppercase letters to make comparison 
                //easier
                str = str.ToUpper();

                if (str[0] == 'Y')   //str[0]is the first letter in the string
                {
                    // continue wit
                    done = true;
                }
                else if (str[0] == 'N')
                {
                    // do not continue with calculation 
                    done = false;
                }
            } while (!done);   //if (!done) is same as: if (done == false)
            return done;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: TIL: `Console.Title` !

Comment: When typing the answer are you using 'y' or 'Y'   'n' or 'N'.  Upper and lowercase letter are not equal in C#

Comment: Read the code, the loop exit only it `done` is `true`. AKA if user entered `Y`. Make an infinite loop `for(;;){...}` and if the user enter a valid answer, directly *return* true or false. Remove the useless `done` variable.

Comment: @DJBurb It's converting the str to uppercase before that?

Comment: `do { .... } while (!done);`. Loop while  _done_ is not true. In other words: Loop as long as _done_ is false. So, when exactly will _done_ turn true (which is the only condition under which the while loop will exit)? Look at your code...

Comment: @NotSmart ah... I missed that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to distinguish 2 different things here:

1. The user wants to continue (which you have)
2. The user made valid input (which you don't have)

You are trying to achieve everything with a single boolean, which will not work.

There are several possibilities to make this work. At your level of understanding, I'd say let's introduce a second boolean:

```cs
private bool RunAgain()
{
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.Write("Run again? (y/n) ");

    bool done = false; //true = y, false = n
    bool validinput = false; // no input is invalid input
    do
    {
        string str = Console.ReadLine();
        str = str.ToUpper();

        if (str[0] == 'Y')
        {
            done = true;
            validinput  = true;
        }
        else if (str[0] == 'N')
        {
            done = false;
            validinput  = true;
        }
    } while (!validinput);  
    return done;
}
```

Note that you have inverse logic here: the method is called `RunAgain()`, and the variable name is called `done`, where my understanding of `done` is that I don't want to continue.

Let's fix that and make shorter code like

```cs
private bool RunAgain()
{
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.Write("Run again? (y/n) ");

    while(true) // yes, it's endless ...
    {
        string str = Console.ReadLine();
        str = str.ToUpper();

        if (str[0] == 'Y')
        {
            return       // ... except if you jump out 
                  false; // False = not run again 
        }
        else if (str[0] == 'N')
        {
            return       // ... except if you jump out 
                  true;  // True = run again 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I had tried to work with two booleans before but also struggled there, however the second solution seems much easier and logical

Comment: @NotSmart: note that I have edited the second answer, because the return values did not correspond to the method name. I'm glad you like the second version more.

Answer (score 1):

This loop here:

```
 do
            {
                string str = Console.ReadLine();
                //change str to uppercase letters to make comparison 
                //easier
                str = str.ToUpper();

                if (str[0] == 'Y')   //str[0]is the first letter in the string
                {
                    // continue wit
                    done = true;
                }
                else if (str[0] == 'N')
                {
                    // do not continue with calculation 
                    done = false;
                }
            } while (!done);   //if (!done) is same as: if (done == false)
```

doesn't have a leaving mechanism when you input `no`. You are checking if they entered `yes` or `no` and if they entered `no` you are just looping over and over again, since `while(!false)` means `while(true)` which means once they enter `no` you are commanding to loop again. You can do something like:

```
            do
            {
                string str = Console.ReadLine();
                //change str to uppercase letters to make comparison 
                //easier
                str = str.ToUpper();

                if (str[0] == 'Y')   //str[0]is the first letter in the string
                {
                    // continue wit
                    done = true;
                }
                else if (str[0] == 'N')
                {
                    // do not continue with calculation 
                    done = false;
                    break;
                }
            } while (!done);   //if (!done) is same as: if (done == false)
            return done;
```

This part is also wrong

```
do
            {
                //Call method to read a number 1 to 7 and display
                //name of the day (1 = Monday, 7 = Sunday with a comment
                PredictTheDay();

                //Calculate the length of a given text
                CalculateStrengthLength();

                //Run again or exit
                done = RunAgain();
            } while (!done);
```

You are receiving a `false` from `RunAgain()` when the user answers `no` which means you should stop the loop but since you again have `while(!done)` you are resolving `!false` to `true`. It should be

```
do
            {
                //Call method to read a number 1 to 7 and display
                //name of the day (1 = Monday, 7 = Sunday with a comment
                PredictTheDay();

                //Calculate the length of a given text
                CalculateStrengthLength();

                //Run again or exit
                done = RunAgain();
            } while (done);
```

Comment: "doesn't have a leaving mechanism. " - well, it *has* a leaving mechanism. You need to enter Y. However, that's not the *expected* leaving condition.

Comment: `do { ... } while (done);` does not sound right.

Comment: @ThomasWeller yes that is what I meant, probably should phrase it better. Also ```do {...} while(done);``` should be right because ```RunAgain()``` return either ```true``` or ```false```. If it receives ```false``` the loop is intended to stop and that is what happens in ```while(done)```. The semantically correct way to do it would be to return ```true``` when the is answer ```no```